# Filter values in Data reader

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a `SqlDataReader` returning data from one table with two columns.

Also have a key value pair collection in which keys are the distinct values of first column in reader.

Now I have to filter the values from the second column of the reader based on the keys available in the collection.

For eg.

```
    Column 1      Column 2
      AZ            130
      AS.           140
      AZ.           150
      AS.           160
```

The dictionary variable will be: `Dictionary('AZ', List<string>[])`.

Distinct of AZ and AS will be in reader.

So here AZ will be key and List will be having 130 and 150. The size of list will be the count of distinct keys.

Comment: Show your C# code: how you make a query, acquire a reader and read this data. It can be easily achieved using LINQ, but we need your code.

Comment: Till now I'm able to make distinct of Column 1 in reader..
reader[0].ToString().Distinct()

Comment: The main thing I'm unable to do is to fetch the value of second column using these keys

Comment: what is the output you need?

Comment: Output will be a Dictionary having keys as distinct of column 1st and values from column 2 inside array of list. And the size of array list is the distinct values of Column 1.. I've already given the example in question

Comment: @Tans If you really want other people to help you, then you need to show your code.

Comment: In column 2 you either need array or a list to hold values for a given key. Not array of list.

Comment: Yes we can keep anything but the major issue is selecting values from Column 2 on the basis of distinct values in Column 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you refuse to show your code for some reason, I will provide a general solution.

You can simply iterate through your rows using `reader.Read()` and collect data into your `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

using (var reader = yourCommand.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string column1 = (string)reader["Column1"];
        string column2 = (string)reader["Column2"];

        if (!dict.ContainsKey(column1))                     
            dict.Add(column1, new List<string>()); 

        dict[column1].Add(column2); 
    }
}
```

It will result in the dictionary, which will have two key-value pairs: "AZ" with a List containing "130" and "150", and "AS" containing "140" and "160".
JSON representation, for clearness:

```
{
    "AZ": ["130", "150"],
    "AS": ["140", "160"]
}
```

Comment: I'm not refusing to show the code..But the reson is I'm sitting in the production environment and copying any code from machine to website will get traced by the company. 
Anyways, thanks a lot for your help I'm checking the code..